# Keeping columns aligned in a div-table containing empty cells

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've a nested group of `<div>` in a table layout, containing a variable number of rows and 6 columns.

```
<div id="table"></div>

var table = document.getElementById("table");
for (var i = 0; i < entities.length; ++i) {
  var row = document.createElement("DIV");
  row.className = "row";
  table.appendChild(row);

  // column 1
  var cell = document.createElement("DIV");
  cell.className = "cell";
  row.appendChild(cell);
  var img = document.createElement("IMG");
  img.src = img1;
  cell.appendChild(img);

  // column 2
  cell = document.createElement("DIV");
  cell.className = "cell";
  row.appendChild(cell);
  img = document.createElement("IMG");
  img.src = img2;
  cell.appendChild(img);

  // column 3
  cell = document.createElement("DIV");
  cell.className = "cell textCell";
  cell.textContent = entities[i].text;
  row.appendChild(cell);

  // column 4
  cell = document.createElement("DIV");
  cell.className = "cell";
  row.appendChild(cell);
  if (entities[i].condition1) {
    img = document.createElement("IMG");
    img.src = img3;
    cell.appendChild(img);
  }

  // column 5
  cell = document.createElement("DIV");
  cell.className = "cell";
  row.appendChild(cell);
  if (entities[i].condition2) {
    img = document.createElement("IMG");
    img.src = img4;
    cell.appendChild(img);
  }

  // column 6
  cell = document.createElement("DIV");
  cell.className = "cell";
  row.appendChild(cell);
  if (entities[i].condition3) {
    img = document.createElement("IMG");
    img.src = img5;
    cell.appendChild(img);
  }

#table { display: table; width: 100%; }
.row { display: table-row; }
.cell { display: table-cell; }
.textCell { width: 100%; }
```

The above snippet of the script generates the table. The image cells autofit around their images, with the text cells filling up the rest of the table. The cells in each column are aligned with each other in general. However, some rows may have 1 or more empty cells in columns 4-6 - there is no consistent pattern and is dependent on the data retrieved from the server. If an image is created in a cell in column 4 or 5 and a later column's cell is empty, the empty cell collapses in and the other cells before that become misaligned.

What I want is for the cells in each column to remain aligned regardless of the circumstances. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Doens't putting a div inside the empty cells work? (DIV the size of the images).

Comment: or add a non breaking space `&nbsp;` inside the empty column

Comment: No on either counts. Adding a `<div>` with the same CSS settings for width and height as the image does nothing. Add a `&nbsp;` only makes the cell as wide as the space. Setting `min-width` does nothing either.